# Not able to parse all the attributes in the given XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, attributes, elementtree

[this in the xml file i need to parse data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhKZq.png)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('2053.0000.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root[1][1].text
```

and i am getting this output:

```
'1081243800'
```

I need all the attributes like username,sex,city,province,country,date and body as a dataframe.

Comment: What data are you trying to access from this XML file? What do you expect your code to output?

Comment: Can you put a link to your XML Files ? Can  you give more details ? What do you want to do ?  Your description is not clear

Comment: https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/XSTK6CPb/file.html
 here is the xml file

Comment: 1) Please post XML as text 2) username, sex, age, city etc are not attributes, they are elements. The only attribute in the XML is "id".

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <posts> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32452122">
      <user id="MS_119052551">
        <username>Carly</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>22</age>
        <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
        <province>Florida</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192907100</date>
      <body>Top 10 weirdest laws in the world Number 10: Most Middle Eastern countries recognize the following Islamic law: "After having sexual relations with a lamb, it is a mortal sin to eat its flesh." (umm OK, I'm sure the lamb appreciates that one)  Number 9: In Lebanon, men are legally allowed to have sex with animals, but the animals must be female. Having sexual relations with a male animal is punishable by death. (OK, like THAT makes sense...)  Number 8: In Bahrain, a male doctor may legally examine a woman's genitals, but is forbidden from looking directly at them during the examination. He may only see their reflection in a mirror. (Ouch!)  Number 7: Muslims are banned from looking at the genitals of a corpse. This also applies to undertakers; the sex organs of the deceased must be covered with a brick or a piece of wood at all times. (...a brick?)  Number 6: The penalty for masturbation in Indonesia is capitation. (Wonder how they enforce that one?)  Number 5: There are men in Guam whose full-time job is to travel the countryside and deflower young virgins, who pay them for the privilege of having sex for the first time. Reason: under Guam law, it is expressly forbidden for virgins to marry. (Now let's just think for a minute...is there any job anywhere else in the world that even comes close to this?)  Number 4: In Hong Kong, a betrayed wife is legally allowed to kill her adulterous husband, but may only do so with her bare hands. (The husband's lover, on the other hand, may be killed in any manner desired. COOL)  Number 3: Topless saleswomen are legal in Liverpool, England, but only in tropical fish stores. (Of course!)  Number 2: In Santa Cruz, Bolivia it is illegal for a man to have sex with a woman and her daughter at the same time. (We have to presume this was a big enough problem that they had to pass this law...)  And the wierdest law in the world is...  In Cali, Colombia, a woman may only have sex with her husband, and the first time this happens her mother must be in the room to witness the act. (I shudder at the thought. How many of us would be virgins today?)..:</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32454893">
      <user id="MS_107984040">
        <username>AM</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>46</age>
        <city>Where I Live in</city>
        <province>OHIO</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192911240</date>
      <body>What if a couple from Santa Cruz, Bolivia went on their honeymoon in Cali, Colombia and things got out of hand with the mom because they had to bring her too to abide by local customs?</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32456453">
      <user id="MS_16913876">
        <username>ThÎµ BÐ¸ÎµÐ¸@ VÎµÐ¸tÐ¸Ñ&#143;@ SÃ¸Ð¸Ð¸d SÑ&#135;stÎµm</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>21</age>
        <city>Oklahoma City</city>
        <province>Oklahoma</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192913880</date>
      <body>doesn't the US own motherfucking guam</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32457969">
      <user id="MS_119486247">
        <username>Camacho Products Inc.</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>27</age>
        <city>Detroit</city>
        <province>MICHIGAN</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192916880</date>
      <body>The weirdest law is the one that makes certain drugs illegal, while other equally dangerous drugs like alcohol remain legal.</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32488106">
      <user id="MS_119052551">
        <username>Carly</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>22</age>
        <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
        <province>Florida</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192979220</date>
      <body> I did. I just want to see how it will go this time. OOps...it doesn't seem to be getting any attention...</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32488391">
      <user id="MS_47511853">
        <username>mark alexander</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>22</age>
        <city>Verdun,</city>
        <province>Quebec</province>
        <country>CA</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192979580</date>
      <body>#5. i should do that as a part-time job. my island's biug enough for a few deflowerers</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32490479">
      <user id="MS_175473882">
        <username>By The Con$ent Of The Governed</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>45</age>
        <city>Tyee City</city>
        <province>California</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1192982460</date>
      <body>Hold all of my calls, I'm moving to Guam...</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32510501">
      <user id="MS_11626085">
        <username>Marty</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>20</age>
        <city>PALOS HEIGHTS</city>
        <province>ILLINOIS</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1193025300</date>
      <body>I wish I lived in guam and had that job.</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32510511">
      <user id="MS_11626085">
        <username>Marty</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>20</age>
        <city>PALOS HEIGHTS</city>
        <province>ILLINOIS</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1193025360</date>
      <body> Yes we do.</body>
    </post> 
 <post id="MS_10266_32511352">
      <user id="MS_11626085">
        <username>Marty</username>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <age>20</age>
        <city>PALOS HEIGHTS</city>
        <province>ILLINOIS</province>
        <country>US</country>
      </user>
      <date>1193027280</date>
      <body>I think I'll use #5 to pay for Law School.</body>
    </post>
</posts> 
'''

data = []
first_level_elements = ['date','body']
second_level_elements = ['username','sex','city','province','country']

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for p in root.findall('.//post'):
  temp = {}
  for e in first_level_elements:
    temp[e] = p.find(e).text
  u = p.find('user')
  for e in second_level_elements:
    temp[e] = u.find(e).text
  data.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```